# Difference between abbr E and abbr M in IA-32 Architectures Software Developer Manual 2C

Tags: architecture, assembly, x86, intel

I am decoding X86 hex code representation to back to assembly. Section A.2.1 of [ISA manual 2C](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-2c-manual.html) provides the abbreviation Codes for Addressing Method (Page A-2 Vol. 2C). Can anyone explain me the what is the difference between abbr E and abbr M ?

> E - A ModR/M byte follows the opcode and specifies the operand. The
>   operand is either a general-purpose register or a memory address. If
>   it is a memory address, the address is computed from a segment
>   register and any of the following values: a base register, an index
>   register, a scaling factor, a displacement.
>
> M - The ModR/M byte may refer only to memory (for example, BOUND, LES,
>   LDS, LSS, LFS, LGS, CMPXCHG8B).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

E can allows any source or destination residing in memory or a register (such as `MOV EAX, DWORD PTR DS:[ESI]` or `MOV EAX, ESI`), where as M only allows memory addresses, which means it cannot address a register, but it can address the memory pointed to by the value in the register (`CMPXCHG8b ESI` is invalid, where as `CMPXCHG8b QWORD PTR DS:[ESI]` is valid).